# using entity framework to connect to azure database throws connecting error

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework-6, database-connection

today we tried to connect to an azure database with entity framework. 
We got an error, which we can't interpret:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Stack overflow and other helping pages has no working solutions for us.
The connection string is correct, the firewall port 1433 is also enabled on both sides (windows and azure).

Does anyone know this problem? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we got the problem. And it's a shame, that it was so simple...
We saved our app.config containing the connectionstring in the wrong project. It has to be in the project of the application, we had it in our Entity Framework project. That was the problem.

For the command update-database you can add the connectionstring to the end:

update-database –TargetMigration “201606011014100_InitialCreate” –ConnectionString “Server=tcp:xyzabcdef.database.windows.net,1433;Data Source=xyzabcdef.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=asdf;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=asdf;Password=asdf;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=20;” –ConnectionProviderName “System.Data.SqlClient”

maybe it helps someone else :)
thanks